# Trigger Ember Error Substate in Route Action

Tags: ember.js, routes

Let's say I have a `BananaNewRoute` that's responsible for displaying the new `Banana` form and creating a `Banana`.

```
App.BananaNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.createRecord('banana')

  actions:    
    create: @currentModel.save().then => @transitionTo "banana", @currentModel
```

Because the input of my application is tightly controlled, it's safe to assume if the server returns any type of error, then it's an application error and there's nothing the user can do about it. I'd like to handle this by transitioning the user to a separate `error` template whenever the `save` action rejects.

I took a look at the [Loading / Error Substates](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) documentation, but it seems like it only works for the `model`, `beforeModel` and `afterModel` hooks. I couldn't get it to work for my `create` action. How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` returns a promise.  The promise's then takes both a passing and a failing function (pardon the converted coffeescript).

```
save().then ((results) ->
  console.log "it worked", results
  return
), (error) ->
  console.log "it failed", error
  return
```

or in javascript, and breaking it down a bit

```
var pass = function(results){};
var fail = function(error){};

save().then(pass, fail);
```

To manually transitionTo the error route, you need only call

```
this.transitionTo('error', reason);
```

Example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xetatoxo/1/edit

The same can be done for deeper error routes

```
this.transitionTo('foo.error', 'it died');
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xetatoxo/2/edit

Comment: Thanks again for the reply @kingpin2k! I got that far, but what I can't figure out is how to trigger Ember's error substate when the save promise is rejected.

Comment: Hey @kingpin2k, would you mind taking another look at this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: oh snap, sorry, I obviously meant to come back here, which error substate, like the error route?

Comment: Not a problem. :) Yep, the error route. My goal is to have one page that's shown whenever there's an error.

Comment: Example added above, honestly I didn't know how to do this, I like the idea, probably a good addition for the documentation.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the reason in the request. Apparently `transitionTo("error")` doesn't work without it. It'd be really cool if there were a way to trigger the error substate automatically whenever a request error occurred. That's how I thought it worked after reading the documentation.

Comment: yeah, it only happens during the model/beforeModel/afterModel hook.

Comment: please see my answer below for a cleaner transition

Answer (score 0):

In order to properly transition to the error substate in your router action you would want to use [Route#intermediateTransitionTo](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_intermediateTransitionTo) which will allow you to transition to the error substate without transitioning the url.

Your updated code would look as follows

```
App.BananaNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> @store.createRecord('banana')

  actions:    
    create: @currentModel.save().then(
      () => @intermediateTransitionTo("banana", @currentModel))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a global error handler for all the promises, like this:

```
// Global error handler for promises
Ember.RSVP.on('error', function(error) {
   //do whatever needed 
});
```

It might be easier to work like this so you don't have to handle errors on every client-server (promise) interaction.